# Proof of $_()∩=1$,$$ is a holomorph, $$ automorphism group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group, semidirect-product, holomorph

I was told that this was a simple proof, by definition of the centraliser and by definition of the intersection with the automorphism group, but I just don't see it.

- $A = \mathrm{Aut}(G)$
- $H = G \rtimes A$
- $C_H(G) = \{h \in H| hg = gh, \forall g \in G\}$

Does $C_H(G) \cap A = 1$ just come from the fact that $H$ doesn't contain automorphisms? I would love some clarity on this, I think maybe I might be confused on what kind of elements are in the holomorph.

Comment: This is just saying that an automorphism of $G$ that maps every element of $G$ to itself is the identity automorphism, which is true by definition. (It might be more helpful to write $C_H(G) \cap A$ as $C_A(G)$.)

Comment: Thanks. How is it saying that? Is $h$ an automorphism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on @Derek's comment, the best course of action is probably to just check what it means for two elements $(1,a)\in A$ and $(g,1)\in G$ to commute (here I identify the groups with their canonical antiprojections in the cartesian product $G\times A$): $(1,a)(g,1)=(a(g),a)$, whereas $(g,1)(1,a)=(g,a)$, which means that the only $a$ satisfying the condition is the identity.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now how to check that the identity is the only permutation that satisfies the requirements of commuting. But how is it that the identity permutation is an element of $H$?

Comment: You should not think in permutations but abstract groups. The identity element is $(1_G,1_A)$, normally written as $(1,1)$ or $1$. Formally $C_A(G)=\{(1_G,1_A)\}$, but in group theory any identity is notated as just $1$.

Comment: Exactly, as @NickyHekster pointed out I am using a sloppy notation here. What I mean is that the first components take values in $G$, while the second range over $A$, so the $1$'s in the first component are the identity element of $G$, whereas the $1$'s in the second one should probably have been called id$_A$ or something similar.